# How can I get a pos tagged file as output when I give a text file as input?

Tags: python, text, part-of-speech

This is the code I am trying but the code is generating an error.

```python
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize 
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) 

file_content = open("Dictionary.txt").read()
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(file_content)

# sent_tokenize is one of instances of 
# PunktSentenceTokenizer from the nltk.tokenize.punkt module 

tokenized = sent_tokenize(tokens) 
for i in tokenized: 
    
    # Word tokenizers is used to find the words 
    # and punctuation in a string 
    wordsList = nltk.word_tokenize(i) 

    # removing stop words from wordList 
    wordsList = [w for w in wordsList if not w in stop_words] 

    # Using a Tagger. Which is part-of-speech 
    # tagger or POS-tagger. 
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(wordsList) 

    print(tagged)
```

**Error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "tag.py", line 12, in 
> tokenized = sent_tokenize(tokens)  File
> "/home/mahadev/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/**init**.py",
>
> line 105, in sent_tokenize return tokenizer.tokenize(text) File
> "/home/mahadev/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py",
>
> line 1269, in tokenize return list(self.sentences_from_text(text,
> realign_boundaries)) File
> "/home/mahadev/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py",
>
> line 1323, in sentences_from_text return [text[s:e] for s, e in
> self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)] File
> "/home/mahadev/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py",
>
> line 1323, in    return [text[s:e] for s, e in
> self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)] File
> "/home/mahadev/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py",
>
> line 1313, in span_tokenize for sl in slices: File
> "/home/mahadev/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py",
>
> line 1354, in _realign_boundaries for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):
> File
> "/home/mahadev/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py",
>
> line 317, in _pair_iter prev = next(it) File
> "/home/mahadev/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py",
>
> line 1327, in _slices_from_text for match in
> self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text): TypeError:
> expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 0):

No idea what your code is supposed to do but the error you are getting is caused by the data type for your *tokens* variable. It wants strings but it's getting a list of a different data type.

You should change that line to:

```
tokens = str(nltk.word_tokenize(file_content))
```